# c# changing method's pointers .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, pointers, code-injection, access-violation, jit

I am trying to replace a method in a plugin loader(Like [Bukkit for Minecraft](https://bukkit.org/)) during run-time. I cannot modify the assembly file directly in this instance. The whole purpose is to be able to tell when the methods are being called. And cancel them if necessary. Once my plugin is loaded I run the following code:

```
public static void PluginLoaded()
{
    replace();
}       

public static void replace()
{
    MethodInfo oldMethod, newMethod;
    oldMethod = typeof(<other assembly>).GetMethod("<method name>", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,null,new Type[]{typeof(ushort)},null);
    newMethod = typeof(NewEvents).GetMethod("<method name>", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(ushort) }, null);
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(oldMethod.MethodHandle);
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(newMethod.MethodHandle);

    ReplaceInner(oldMethod, newMethod);
}

static void ReplaceInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
{
    unsafe
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            int* inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
            int* tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
        else
        {
            ulong* inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
            ulong* tar = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine until the original program tries to call the changed method. When it does this the whole program stops and I get a [access volation](http://pastebin.com/XUD6DiE6). How do I fix this?

Comment: I take it you have a plug-in architecture in your application and are trying to have wrapper logic for tracking method calls into the plugin(s)? Have you tried a dependency injection framework such as Managed Extensibility Framework or Microsoft Unity? Those provide ways to implement wrappers around dynamically loaded assemblies to do stuff like this.

Comment: Which version of framework?

Comment: Try it without calling `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod()`.

Comment: @Mr Anderson Oh sorry, its .NET 3.5.

Comment: This function does not work until 4.0. Look at this site, specifically the comments thread where they discuss how the memory map of a type has changed between 3.5 and 4.0. If you update your framework, this will work with or without `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod()`. If you cannot upgrade the framework, refer to the original examples. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment about removing the offset because it's more complex than that. Did you try upgrading your framework version? Upgrading it on your machine would do the trick - wouldn't even need to upgrade Visual Studio https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643

Comment: I cant upgrade because the loader doesn't support more than .net 3.5(Its using unity)

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you have provided is specific for the memory mapping of the CLR starting in .Net version 4.0. Here are your options:

Option 1. Upgrade the .NET Framework on your machine. This should fix your issue without the need to upgrade visual studio. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643

Option 2. Update your `ReplaceInner()` method to reflect the memory mapping of Types and Methods before the .NET framework 4.0:

```
static void ReplaceInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
{
    unsafe
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            uint* tarPtr = (uint*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();
            uint* injPtr = (uint*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();

            uint* tar = (uint*)*(tarPtr + 5) + 12;
            uint* inj = (uint*)*(injPtr + 5) + 12;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
        else
        {
            ulong* tarPtr = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();
            ulong* injPtr = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();

            ulong* tar = (ulong*)*(tarPtr + 5) + 12;
            ulong* inj = (ulong*)*(injPtr + 5) + 12;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @michaelbecker I changed the code slightly. Try this.

Comment: @michaelbecker when did this exception occur? When running `ReplaceInner()` or when calling your new injected method?

Comment: when calling ReplaceInner(). Using Try{}Catch{} Ive figured out that its this code thats doing it "*tar = *inj;".(For the 2nd one as im on x64)

Comment: @michaelbecker I don't currently have access to a 64-bit environment to debug this - I will help when I can.

Comment: Throws NullReferenceException in x64 for `*tar = *inj`. Has anyone figured out how it can be made to work in x64 mode?