# Get "original" datetime

Tags: c#, php, mysql, httpclient

I'm creating a program that has a date-based license, if passed from the expiration date the license is invalid. However, my problem was:

If the user changed the date of the computer, he would change the program as well and thus "hack" the program. I solved it this way:

In PHP I get the date now of the server Hosting / MySQL:

127.0.0.1/getdateserver.php

```
$query  = "SELECT NOW() as `now`";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $row    = $result->fetch_array();
        $now    = $row['now'];
        echo "$now";
```

In C# i make request for every second for my site and return date now:

```
 private Timer timer;
private DateTime timeserver;

    public void InitTimer()
            {
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
                timer.Interval = 1000;
                timer.Start();
            }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    setDateServerAsync();
    }

        private async void setDateServerAsync()
                {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("127.0.0.1/getdateserver.php");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    timerserver = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
```

Everything working perfectly. But this method does many requests per minute (RPM), and since I can have multiple users using the program the number only increases. So my question is: Are there any other methods that can be effective?

PS: My program only works with internet

Comment: Why are you making a request every second? Wouldn't it be enough to get the time every minute? 1 more minute of use isn't going to put you at a huge loss.

Comment: Even so, if I have many users the requests only increase. But it can be a solution too.

Comment: You have a **date**-based license, not a time-of-day-based license. It should be sufficient to poll for the server date every 12 to 24 hours, no? Also, if you are insisting on checking not only date but also time, be aware of time zones and daylight saving. Your customers might not be happy if you get this wrong and their license expires prematurely...

Comment: I forgot to quote in the topic, I am informing the days that are missing and the hours for the user. So the solution would be to set the timer for each hour? elgonzo I using dateexpire> = timerserver would cause problems with daylight saving time?

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to do that. I think you are overcomplicating things for no real benefit here. Your licenses are **date**-based. Why are you obsessing about the time of the day? Since your licenses are date-based, they expire at the end of some day. Why do you need to show the user the time that is left until the end of the day? The user knows when a day ends -- at midnight...

Comment: And why are you executing any SQL for this at all? PHP has, for instance, [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: Is this method the most effective? Or would he have another?

Comment: @RainMaster: Make a check on Programm start and then once per hour. That is **way** enough precision and load for this.

Comment: I was wondering if you check the license expiration date on client side after you get the correct date. If this is the case, someone can crack this protection by intercepting requests made to the server and return the same date over and over and the license will never expire.

Comment: When the client login in to the program, it makes a request to get its data (including expiration date). How can I prevent this "crack"?

Comment: You should check it server-side and application functionality disabled or reduced as you wish. Of course, I'm giving you this hint because you stated: "only works with the internet". You can do the check at authentication time only but consider that the authentication, in this case, should expire (ie. after few days) otherwise your license may last far beyond expiration, alternatively, you can check it by using other ways. If your application is using the internet only to check license expiration, sooner or later you'll be cracked. What is not easily crackable are server-side services.

Comment: Protecting a .NET program against "cracking" is a fool's errand (if there was ever a perfect fool's errand, this is coming very close to it). "Cracking" of such license/protection schemes can be done much simpler than doing an elaborate man-in-the-middle/proxy "server simulation". Remember, C# is compiled into IL byte code for the CLR and can be EASILY decompiled with tools like ILSpy. With such an insight into the program, it will be rather trivial to replace the license check method(s) with other methods that will always pretend that the license exists and is valid. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) How such method swapping would work, you ask? Well, look here for some example of how simple it really is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213674/c-sharp-changing-methods-pointers-net-3-5. The only way you can make "cracking" harder (not impossible) is to compile your program into hard-to-decompile and painful-to-debug native code... What i am trying to say with my longwinded comment here: Save your time and your breath and spend your energy on something more useful than fruitlessly trying to protect your program against cracking/tampering.

Comment: @elgonzo I think that if your .NET software (ie. running on your PC) depends on a remote server API/service you can just block the remote API via server-side checking when the license expires. Any protection at client-side is useless, we agree on this. I've personally cracked software with client-side authentication with no easy .NET nor Java decompilation by using IDA-Pro, pure assemly: it was not so difficult either.